# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on Z97X-gaming gt with nvidia geforce gtx 780ti card

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

How to install ubuntu 14.04 dual boot with windows 7 on a SSD, system is Z97X-gaming gt with nvidia geforce gtx 780ti card and intel i7 4790k

So far after getting throught install the machine restarts and i get purple outline with black center before it goes to black screen, i had to use nomodeset option in boot menu other wise i get black screen on install.  Windows 7 is on the SSD with unallocated space which using the installer i turned into

one partition 75gb,Primary, ext4, mount point /

one partition 34gb, logical swap area

and put the boot loader on /dev/sdb (as sda is a 3tb drive and i left it alone)

In frustration i tried just installing ubuntu using the erase disk and install ubuntu option in the installer, however this had the same issue as above